# For each loops not executing

Tags: java, loops, foreach

For some reason all the `for-each` loops in my method are completely ignored, and I cannot figure out why. Here is my code:

```
private static boolean notUsed(ArrayList<Integer> check, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> used)
  {
    boolean c1 = false;
    boolean c2 = true;
    for (ArrayList<Integer> item : used) // Not executed
    {
      System.out.println("It works!");
      Collections.sort(item);
      Collections.sort(check);
      if (check.equals(item)) c1 = true;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> existing = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int item : check)
    {
      for (int exists : existing) // Not executed
      {
        if (exists == item) 
        {
          c2 = false;
          break;
        }
        else existing.add(item);
      }
      if (c2 == false) break;
    }
    if (c1 && c2) return true;
    else return false;
  }
```

I have been going over it for the past 15 minutes and fail to see why the code refuses to bother with the contents of the loops. In fact, I didn't even know java could avoid executing loops before now. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried changing int to Integer in your Foreach loop? There is a difference. One is a primitive and one is an Object so that might be your problem.

Comment: What is the size of your ArrayList?

Comment: When you say for (ArrayList<Integer> item : used) // Not executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a new ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Integer> existing = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

which is empty.

When the foreach runs, it has nothing to iterate over. Therefore, your *"not executing"* comment is perfectly valid.

The first loop however, depends on what exactly is passed. Put some print statemtents figure out the size of the List. Most likely, that is 0 as well, which again, causes the loop to be "skipped".

Comment: Ah, well there's the problem then... Lemme fix that and see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are missing something obvious.

If those loops aren't executing, then there are no elements in the arguments passed to the routine.

Answer (score 1):

size of `used` must be 0 and the second loop is not executing because `existing` is a new ArrayList and its size is definitely 0

Answer (score 0):

here is working code..this will give you idea. As others mentioned..there would not be any elements to iterate...because i ran the below code and for each loop works...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;


public class Test1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> used = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer>item = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        item.add(1);
        used.add(item);
        notUsed(item,used );
    }

    private static boolean notUsed(ArrayList<Integer> check, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> used)
      {
        boolean c1 = false;
        boolean c2 = true;
        for (ArrayList<Integer> item : used) // Not executed
        {
          System.out.println("It works!");
          Collections.sort(item);
          Collections.sort(check);
          if (check.equals(item)) c1 = true;
        }
        ArrayList<Integer> existing = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int item : check)
        {
          for (int exists : existing) // Not executed
          {
            if (exists == item) 
            {
              c2 = false;
              break;
            }
            else existing.add(item);
          }
          if (c2 == false) break;
        }
        if (c1 && c2) return true;
        else return false;
      }

}
```